# How to Embed camera in HTML page for cordova mobile app?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, camera

I'm developing a mobile app using Cordova and would like to know if there's a way I could get the camera to work embedded on my application( HTML).

I know Cordova has a camera function but it just goes to the native camera app. I wanted it to show the camera feed on the html.

already used https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview but camera quality is very poor...

Comment: There are many examples available online - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/tutorials/cordova-camera-app-tutorial/   ,   http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/05/03/tutorial-camera-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/  and Use cordova plugin  - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Those examples do not solve the problem. You missed the bit where he wanted to have the camera view embedded in the application.

Most camera plugins open an external camera app to take a photo, and then when the camera app is completed, the image is returned to the calling app as a base64 string.